# How to remove quotation marks from std::filesystem::path

Tags: c++, c++17, std-filesystem

If I use functions like `absolute()` I always get a path which contains quotation marks.

Is there a way within the filesystem functions to remove this quotation marks which enables it to use with e.g. std::ifstream?

```
  fs::path p2 { "./test/hallo.txt" };
  std::cout << "absolte to file : " << fs::absolute(p2) << std::endl;
```

returns:

> ```
> "/home/bla/blub/./test/hallo.txt"
> ```

I need

> ```
> /home/bla/blub/./test/hallo.txt
> ```

instead.

It is no problem to do it manually, but I want to ask if there is a method inside the filesystem lib.

Comment: Which platform?

Comment: @JohnZwinck I thought the idea behind using std::filesystem is, that I remove platform dependency :-) I currently use linux, but code must be portable.

Comment: [How to get full path by just giving filename?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27247991/how-to-get-full-path-by-just-giving-filename)

Comment: Congratulations! You may be the first person to find a use for [`std::quoted`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/quoted).

Comment: If you think platform independence is possible on a filesystem you are in for a bad surprise!

Comment: I might be missing something but... you do realize that it's the `operator<<` overload for `boost::filesystem::path` that emits the double quotes?

Comment: @G.M.: No! Thanks for that hint. As also given by answer from Quentin path.string() gives the correct result. Thanks!

Answer (score 27, accepted):

[`std::operator << (std::filesystem::path const &)`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/path/operator_ltltgtgt) is specified as follows:

> Performs stream input or output on the path p. [`std::quoted`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/quoted) is used so that spaces do not cause truncation when later read by stream input operator.

So this is expected behaviour when streaming a path. What you need is [`path::string()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/path/string):

> Returns the internal pathname in native pathname format, converted to specific string type.

```
std::cout << "absolte to file : " << absolute(p2).string() << std::endl;
//                                               ^^^^^^^^^
```

I've also removed `fs::` since `absolute` can be found via ADL.